# How I can color words inside array in codemirror in diffrente color?

Tags: css, colors, codemirror

I have array of word build dynamic on event **cursoractivity** ,

**what I do is :**
I build my own language from metadata store in xml file so when I type on codemirror :

car.whell.circle.number  employee.getname()

I store all the words in array like this :
[image: every word with the type]

so I store every word with it's type ,

**Note :**
if I have tow class :

The name of first class is Data and it's fields are:

fname, lname, age

The name of second class is info and its fields are:

mother, father

To color the fields in specific color only if it comes after the name of own class (i.e when I type on codemirror **Data.fname** I want to color the word **fname** in green color But when I type on codemirror **info.fname** I did not want to color the word **fname** in green color because (**fname** not contain in the class "info")) so I build dynamic array store the words after i check if I can color it ,so every word in dynamic array I can color it, the useful of my dynamic array to knew if I can color the word or I can not .

**what I want to do :**

I want to color every word it's type : **class** by  red color, and the the word it's type **classsomthing** by blue color, and the word it's type (primitive like int,string) by green color , so any body can help me How I can color the words in my dynamic array only if it come in the specific order in my dynamic array and with color define by type stored in my dynamic array??
Thanks in advance